# How to preload data in realm without using internet?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a fitness app and I need to upload database with exercises, descriptions of exercises, images of exercises etc. and then save it in Realm for future use in app. The data won't be edited or removed, it is only needed for populate tableviews. I get data with calling api during first launch. But the main problem is that what if user download app and then e.g. turn off the internet. Is there a way to call this api during download app to prevent situations like described above? Maybe better way is copy this data by hand to csv to avoid calling api (using internet)?

Here is my code of getting data

```
 struct MyExercisesInfo: Decodable {
        var results: [MyExerciseInfo]
    }
    
    struct MyExerciseInfo: Decodable {
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var category: MyCategory
    }
    
    struct ExerciseInfoRequest: Decodable {
        let resourceURL: URL
        
        init() {
            let resourceString = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exerciseinfo/?language=2"
            guard let resourceURL = URL(string: resourceString) else { fatalError()}
            self.resourceURL = resourceURL
        }
        
        func getData(completion: @escaping(Result<[MyExerciseInfo], CategoryError>) -> 
        Void) {
            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL) { data, _, _ in
                guard let jsonData = data else {
                    completion(.failure(.noDataAvailable))
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let categoryResponse = try decoder.decode(MyExercisesInfo.self, from: jsonData)
                    let myCategories = categoryResponse.results
                    completion(.success(myCategories))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
                }
                
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    
    struct MyExercisesInfo: Decodable {
        var results: [MyExerciseInfo]
    }
    
    struct MyExerciseInfo: Decodable {
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var category: MyCategory
    }
    
    struct ExerciseInfoRequest: Decodable {
        let resourceURL: URL
        
        init() {
            let resourceString = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exerciseinfo/?language=2"
            guard let resourceURL = URL(string: resourceString) else { fatalError()}
            self.resourceURL = resourceURL
        }
        
        func getData(completion: @escaping(Result<[MyExerciseInfo], CategoryError>) -> Void) {
            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceURL) { data, _, _ in
                guard let jsonData = data else {
                    completion(.failure(.noDataAvailable))
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let categoryResponse = try decoder.decode(MyExercisesInfo.self, from: jsonData)
                    let myCategories = categoryResponse.results
                    completion(.success(myCategories))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.canNotProcessData))
                }
                
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    
        
    }
```

Comment: Your best bet is to check if the data is downloaded or not, instead of checking internet. When app launches, if the app doesn't download, just show an Alert saying "Unable to download data needed to launch the app." Then the user should be able to see they need internet to load the app. On my apps that use this technique, we usually have offline versions of the tables also just in case they don't have internet. Once they have internet, your code can check if the table is updated or not.

Comment: I have to admit that is wise solution. So do you recommend to do offline shorter version in case of user launch first time app being offline?

Comment: Yeah at least your company's logos, and some small sized images for your design. Or at least some type of page that instructs the user the app is still gathering content.

Comment: And you could even update the "Offline Table" in Realm when the app has internet, if necessary. Just make sure your launch version has a small table for offline start (in case).